# Error in the fetching contents of email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, multipart

I have written code for fetching contents of multipart email...I am getting this error...I know this error is due to something very silly but i am unable to get it after hours of debugging...probably some silly error like ;,} etc.
code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder;
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage;
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPNestedMessage;



private String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {


    if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
        // prefer html text over plain text
        Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
        String text = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
            Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
            if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                if (text == null)
                    text = getText(bp);
                continue;
            } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                String s = getText(bp);
                if (s != null)
                    return s;
            } else {
                return getText(bp);
            }
        }
        return text;
    } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
            String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
            if (s != null)
                return s;
        }
    }
    else
    { return p.getContent().toString();}  
    return null; 
} 

public class FolderFetch3 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    IMAPFolder folder = null;
    Store store = null;
    String subject = null;
    Flag flag = null;




    try 
    {
      Properties props = System.getProperties();
      props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

      store = session.getStore("imaps");
      store.connect("imap.gmail.com","hjcooljohny75@gmail.com", "ferry@786");

      //folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Spam"); // This doesn't work for other email account
      folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("inbox"); //This works for both email account


      if(!folder.isOpen())
      folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
      Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
      System.out.println("No of Messages : " + folder.getMessageCount());
      System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
      System.out.println(messages.length);
      for (int i=messages.length-1; i > messages.length-10;i--) 
      {

        System.out.println("*****************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("MESSAGE " + (i + 1) + ":");
        MimeMessage msg =  (MimeMessage)messages[i];
        //System.out.println(msg.getMessageNumber());
        //Object String;
        //System.out.println(folder.getUID(msg)
       //String n =messages[i];
        subject = msg.getSubject();

        System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
        System.out.println("From: " + msg.getFrom()[0]);
        System.out.println("To: "+msg.getAllRecipients()[0]);
        System.out.println("Date: "+msg.getReceivedDate());
        System.out.println("Size: "+msg.getSize());
        System.out.println(msg.getMessageID());
        System.out.println(msg.getFlags());
        String tex=getText(msg);
        System.out.println("Body: \n"+ tex);
        System.out.println(msg.getContentType());

      }
    }
    finally 
    {
      if (folder != null && folder.isOpen()) { folder.close(true); }
      if (store != null) { store.close(); }
    }

}



}
```

I am getting this error:

```
FolderFetch3.java:17: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    private String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {
            ^
FolderFetch3.java:23: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            String text = null;
            ^
FolderFetch3.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
            ^
FolderFetch3.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                            ^
FolderFetch3.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                                               ^
FolderFetch3.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                ^
FolderFetch3.java:29: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                    continue;
                    ^
FolderFetch3.java:30: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                ^
FolderFetch3.java:32: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                    if (s != null)
                    ^
FolderFetch3.java:34: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                } else {
                ^
FolderFetch3.java:36: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                }
                ^
FolderFetch3.java:39: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        ^
FolderFetch3.java:41: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
            ^
FolderFetch3.java:41: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                            ^
FolderFetch3.java:41: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                                               ^
FolderFetch3.java:43: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                if (s != null)
                ^
FolderFetch3.java:45: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            }
            ^
FolderFetch3.java:48: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        { return p.getContent().toString();}  
                                           ^
FolderFetch3.java:50: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
```

^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `getText(Part p)` method inside the `FolderFetch3` class.